# Problem with changing calendar to french in IE10

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer, angular-material

I am using two datepickers in my web app to filter data by choosing a start and an end date. I used mat-datepicker of Angular Materials.

I have to display the calendar in french, so I used the following code:

```
constructor(private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>) {
    // Change calendar to french version
    this.dateAdapter.setLocale('fr');
}
```

This works perfectly in chrome and mozilla. But in IE10 I still have the calendar in english.
Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is my pollyfill.ts content:

```
.....
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

import 'core-js/es7/symbol';
import 'core-js/es7/object';
import 'core-js/es7/math';
import 'core-js/es7/string';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
import 'core-js/es7/map';
import 'core-js/es7/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es7/set';
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

Comment: Salut, I do not answer your problem but I found this for the selection of a period with `mat-datepicker`, [StackBlitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-datepicker-period)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Material Datepicker document](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview), I create a sample using the following code, it works well in IE 10, you could refer to it:

code in the component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {MomentDateAdapter} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';

import * as _moment from 'moment';
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-duplicate-imports
//import {default as _rollupMoment} from 'moment';

const moment =  _moment;

export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-material-datepicker',
  templateUrl: 'material-datepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['material-datepicker.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},

    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
})
export class MaterialDatepickerComponent {

  constructor(private adapter: DateAdapter<Date>) {
    this.adapter.setLocale('fr');
  }
  date = new FormControl(moment());
}
```

Code in the conponent.html:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" placeholder="Verbose datepicker" [formControl]="date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

The package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-material-sample",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.2",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^7.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```

Then, the result like this:

[image]